# Why is the meta SE welcome page cut off on the right?

Tags: feature-request

I can't read the end of the guidelines because they're cut off. Looks like this might be a question asked and closed before.How long has this been like this and when will it be fixed?

Comment: Which page are you talking about?

Comment: Well, at the top of the page its labeled exactly as I typed it in my question. In my browser history its listed as "tour meta stack exchange".

Comment: I'm not seeing anything cut off, can you post a screenshot or explain a bit more what you mean by cut off? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: It might take me an hour to figure out how to do that. I could try copying and pasting, but don't know if this would display right. I might take a picture of it with my camera. What I'm seeing though as I scroll down the page is panels slide out from the right, but don't slide out all the way. They're the ones with the orange arrows pointing at them showing acceptable ways to ask questions. I'm using a firefox browser. Maybe I should try internet explorer. I'm going back to math SE with my chrome computer. Haven't been able to submit a question there either.

Comment: The things that slide out are `status-bydesign` they aren't really instructions on the right, they point to different features. The instructions are on the left of the page with the flyouts on right.

Comment: I'll try this later on my chrome book. Anyway they're not sliding out all the way on this display.